# Why do different browsers show different outputs for my flask using jquery code?

Tags: jquery, python, html

I have very less experience of web development. I am trying to make changes in an already written code which uses python flask, jquery and HTML. The code initially had an input field with a submit button, in which if the user enters a value, the result was displayed on the screen. I made some changes to add one more input form and a submit button to enter the email address of the user so that the output can be sent as an email attachment. All these modules are running perfectly fine individually. But if I run it on different browsers ( I tried IE, chrome and firefox), they give different kinds of unexpected outputs. Is it something with the code or with the browser?

the code looks something like this:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% import "bootstrap/fixes.html" as fixes %}
{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as util %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<style>
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#error {
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color: #FFA5A5;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

td { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container" style="width:92%">

    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/job/irrexplorer/master/docs/irrexplorer-logo.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <form id="form" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                    <input type="text" name="data" class="form-control" />
                    <button id="btnsearch" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="Search" onclick="func1()">Search</button>
                </form>
        <form id="form2" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                    <input type="text" name="data2" id="emailinput" class="form-control" />
                    <button id="btnsearch2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search2" value="Search2" onclick="func2()">Search</button>
                </form>
                {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
                    <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>

        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="row" id="loading" style="display:none">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"><img src="/static/img/loading.gif"/></div>
        </div>
        <div id="error"></div>

        {% for table in tables %}
        <h4>{{ table.title }}</h4>
        <div>
            <table id="{{ table.id }}" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
            {% if table.note %}
            <div>{{ table.note }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>


  </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{{super()}}
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// source: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/js/plugins.js
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.

function func1(){
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeline', 'timelineEnd', 'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());

$(document).ready(function () {

    {% for table in tables %}
    setup_table("{{ table.id }}", "{{ table.url }}", {{ table.start_fields|safe }} );
    {% endfor %}

});

function setup_table(table_id, data_url, start_fields) {

    state_loading();
    $.ajax({
        url: data_url,
        success: function (data) {
            state_loaded();
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            populatetable('#' + table_id, result, start_fields);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            state_loaded();
            error_message = $(error.responseText).filter("p").text();
            console.log(error_message);
            $("#error").text(error_message);
            $("#error").show()
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
}


function func2(){
    var e = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
    $.ajax({
            data : {
                    email : $('#emailinput').val()
                   },
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/emailid'
                  })
            alert("email sent");

}

</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{{super()}}
{{fixes.ie8()}}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think people will need to see the code in order to help

Comment: You don't seem to have an element called `emailinput`, so `document.getElementById("emailinput")` is presumably causing one of the errors? What do the web consoles show?

Comment: Well that isn't the problem. I had posted the wrong version of the code before. I corrected it now. (This is my first ever question on stackoverflow. Pardon me for any errors)